# Store different types of data in one Hive Box

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

I am using Flutter and Hive to store data.
I have created Boxes for several different primitive types (list - map - string).

I read the docs but it's still unclear.

Is it possible to store different types in one Box? Currently I am using different boxes to hold different types.

I want to store list map and strings in a single box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can, its mentioned in their documentation [here](https://docs.hivedb.dev/#/basics/read_write?id=write)

```
var box = Hive.box('myBox');

box.put('name', 'Paul');

box.put('friends', ['Dave', 'Simon', 'Lisa']);

box.put(123, 'test');

box.putAll({'key1': 'value1', 42: 'life'});
```

Comment: how should i open the box , it needs a type, i'll just put object? as a type
final loginInfoBox = await Hive.openBox<Object?>('login');